# ChartJs doesn't display the line item legend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, legend

Here's the code:
[image]

And here's the result:
[image]

As you can see, no legend

Answer (score 0):

I fond out in the meanwhile. Chart.register was missing the "Legend" plugin.
Legend is imported from 'chart.js' same as the others:
[image]
[image]